Do the adjunctions in change of rings also apply to sheaves?
I'm wondering if the change of rings adjunctions also apply to sheaves.
Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $\phi : O_A \rightarrow O_B$ be a morphism of sheaves of rings on $X$. Let $F$ : $O_B-mod \rightarrow O_A-mod$ be the forgetful functor. I want to prove that $F$ has a left adjoint $M \rightarrow M \otimes_{O_A} O_B$ and a right adjoint $M \rightarrow \mathcal{H}om_{O_A}(O_B, M)$ , where $M$ is a sheaf of $O_A$-modules, and $\mathcal{H}om$ denotes sheaf Hom.
I want to apply the adjunctions for modules over a ring, but I got stuck.
Let $M$ be a sheaf of $O_A$-modules, and $N$ be a sheaf of $O_B$-modules. Let $U \subseteq X$ be open.
For tensor product, we have $M \otimes_{O_A} O_B$ is the sheafification of $U \rightarrow M(U) \otimes_{O_A(U)} O_B(U)$. Thus, by looking at presheaves, we have a bijection
$$Hom_{O_B(U)-mod}(M(U) \otimes_{O_A(U)} O_B(U), N(U)) \simeq Hom_{O_A(U)-mod}(M(U), N(U))$$
These commute with restriction, so we get a bijection
$$Hom_{pre-O_B-mod}(M \otimes_{O_A}^{pre} O_B, N) \simeq Hom_{O_A-mod}(M, N)$$
Applying the universal property of sheafification gives the desired result.
Now, for Hom, this is where I got stuck. I want to find a bijection
$$Hom_{O_A-mod}(N, M) \simeq Hom_{O_B-mod}(N, \mathcal{H}om_{O_A}(O_B, M))$$
$\mathcal{H}om_{O_A}(O_B,  M)(U)$ is not usually equal to $Hom_{O_A(U)}(O_B(U), M(U))$, so I don't know how to apply the adjunction from modules to sheaves in this case.

You have to define $\mathcal{H}om_{O_A}(O_B,  M)(U)$ as the $\mathcal{O}_B(U)$-module of $\mathcal{O}_A|_U$-module homomorphisms $\mathcal{O}_B|_U \to N|_U$. As you have noticed, it is not sufficient to just take global sections. This is a straight forward generalization of the sheaf hom (i.e., the internal hom in the category of sheaves on $X$), and your adjunction is Stacks/0A6F.
It may be useful to know that for every topos and a homomorphism of rings $A \to B$ in that topos we get a right adjoint of the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Mod}_B \to \mathbf{Mod}_A$. Once you have understood that the construction for the topos of sets uses nothing special about sets and works in this generality, we may just apply it to the topos of sheaves on $X$. This is a powerful point of view, since from the "inside" of that topos, sheaves of rings are just "normal rings". The usual formula $\mathrm{Hom}_A(B,-)$ for the right adjoint is valid.
